# Does IBMQ real devices support reset gate in runtime? Because I'm facing the error :

Tags: ibm-cloud, quantum-computing, qiskit, post-quantum-cryptography

Failed - TranspilerError: "Unknown operation type for DAGOpNode(op=Instruction(name='reset', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qargs=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(7, 'q'), 0),), cargs=()).

I need a device which supports reset gate when ran using qiskit runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the backends supporting reset with the following code:

```py
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
provider = IBMProvider()
for backend in provider.backends(simulator=False):
    if 'reset' in supported_instructions:
        print(backend.name, 'supports reset')
    else:
        print(backend.name, 'DOES NOT supports reset')
```